# Conditionally "mutate" a column (whether or not add a column)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Just as the title says, I'm trying to conditionally add a mutate step to my dplyr pipe. But I'm getting errors.  Is there a tidy solution?  Here's a simple example...

```
max.mpg <- 50
mtcars %>%
  {
    if(!!max.mpg > 10) mutate(foo = 1) else . 
  }
```

But the above generates the following error:

```
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

What I'm trying to do is add a new variable to the mtcars data frame--but *only* upon a given condition. If the condition is `FALSE`, then I just want the original data frame returned.

Interestingly, if I change the above condition to evaluate as `FALSE` (such as by writing, `if(!!max.mpg > 60)`), then the script runs fine. So, the problem indeed appears to reside in the mutate verb.

Finally, and in case it greatly affects the solution, I've got the above embedded inside a custom function. But I think if I can get the simple script correct in the above, I can work the rest out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need tidyeval

```r
library(dplyr)

max.mpg <- 50

mtcars %>% {if(max.mpg > 10) mutate(., foo=1) else .}

#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb foo
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   1
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   1
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   1
...

mtcars %>% {if(max.mpg > 60) mutate(., foo=1) else .}  

#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
...
```

Comment: Brilliant!  This does it. When the condition is TRUE (i.e., max.mpg > 10), your code returns a data frame containing foo.  And when the condition is FALSE, it returns the mtcars data frame unaffected.  And I see now how my original syntax was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like what you are trying to evaluate doesn't have anything to do with the data set as you are defining max.mpg and then comparing that to a constant. I assume what you are trying to do is is flag when mpg is greater than max.mpg, in that case this should work

```
library (dplyr)
max.mpg <- 50

mtcars %>% mutate(foo=if_else(mpg>max.mpg, true = 1, false = 0))
```

With a value of 50 all the rows evaluate the same, if that is changed to something within the mpg range can see that it evaluates conditionally.

```
max.mpg <- 20

mtcars %>% mutate(foo=if_else(mpg>max.mpg, true = 1, false = 0))
```

Comment: Thanks @BEVAN.  Yea, I had tried code (not shown in my post) along the lines of what you suggested.  It runs. But what I want to do is return the original data frame (without column foo) if the condition doesn't apply at all.  However, with your solution, the resulting data frame contains foo regardless. That is, the resulting df contains foo when max.mpg <-20 and also when max.mpg <- 50.

Comment: How about this then?  ```mtcars %>% mutate(foo=if_else(mpg>max.mpg, true = 1, false = 0))%>% filter(foo==1)%>% select(-foo)```

Comment: @BEVAN you need to read the `if_else` syntax. That's not how it works. In terms of using `select`, we can try `select_if` and remove `foo` if the rows are not equal to the desired value. All in all, you need to revisit the question. What you're proposing suggests that you've not fully understood the question.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `case_when()` function from dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)  
mtcars %>% mutate(foo = case_when(max.mpg > 10 ~ 1, TRUE~.))
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  FWIW, I get an error when running the above.  It appears dplyr doesn't like the vary last clause in the case_when() statement: `TRUE~.`